# Get status code from HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net, request, sitecore, http-status-codes

is it possible to get HTTP status code from current request (HttpRequest)? I am redirecting one page to another page with code 301. But when I am on redirected page, the page has in its response status code 200. In a browser I can see right code (301).

Answer (score 10):

When redirecting page to another (no matter if the status you redirect with **301** or **302** status), there are 2 requests:

1. First request for which the response status is **301** (or **302**) with the new location
2. Second request for which the response status will be **200** (assuming everything is ok) with the content of the **redirected** page.

When you check `Response.StatusCode` on the **redirecting** page, it will be **301**, but on the **redirected** page it will never be **301** (unless you're doing another redirection after the first one).

To get the HTTP status code from the response of current request, use:

```c#
HttpContext.Current.Response.Status // to get the string like '200 OK'
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode // to get only the int value, e.g. 200
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. Because when I do a redirect with custom status code, it is actual only for the current http context. So when I am on redirected page, I have new status code because I have new (independent) http context.

Answer (score 3):

To simply see the status code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode
```

Comment: So what do you want to do?